# How to unpack the resource from another module in a multimodule package properly?

Tags: java, python, maven, swagger

I use Maven to work with a multi module where it has multiple modules.

- One of them is a JAX-RS project (let's called it `module-jax-rs`. I use `swagger-maven-plugin` to generate Swagger json and bundle it as a resource in `module-jax-rs`.
- Another module `module-python` is a python module where it relies on Swagger Json in `module-jax-rs` to generate a Swagger client using another Maven plugin `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`
- However, to do so, I need to unpack `swagger.json` file from `module-jax-rs` before compile `module-python`.
- This works fine with `mvn package` but not with `mvn compile` since `mvn compile` does not generate the package that I can extract from.

What should I do to make it possible to still run `mvn compile` without running into the following error?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:
maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack-dependencies (unpack) 
on project module-python: Artifact has not been packaged yet. 
When used on reactor artifact, unpack should be executed after
packaging: see MDEP-98. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Post the `pom.xml` of the failing module.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically copy the swagger.json into the module-python with something like the antrun plugin and the file's relative path.

However this is not really the proper way of doing using resources from another module even one in the same multi-module project.  Generally the correct way to use resources from other modules is to allow the module with the required resources to package and install those resources into a jar files, and then simply import that jar file in any module that needs it.  Of course for this to happen you have to run the package goal.

I am not sure why you are trying to avoid the package goal.  I have never come across a situation where there was good reason for not running it.